# Publishing Android app that have been converted to blackberry

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry

You might have heard about that BlackBerry is giving away PlayBooks if you submit and get approved with your app inbefore 13th this month, and its getting close, and I am quite worried.

So I've already sent the .bar to get approved but I am not sure did I submit the right one. You see, when you add BlackBerry nature to your Android project(Eclipse) and build and sign for BlackBerry it will add multiple files on the "dist" folder and its sub folders.

Did I do it correctly if I sent the one in the "dist" folder for them to approve or would it have been some of those in the sub folder like "PROJECT45435436436.bar" or what they're even for? I wish they had better instructions for it but I probably have to cross my fingers and hope I did right thing!

If the luck isn't on my side, I always got you stackoverflow. Can you tell me, which one am I supposed to submit from the dist folder if any of them, if not, is there some other tool for signing publically? I did use the eclipse plugin signing tool and it told me that it was done but didn't tell what file it signed.

Comment: too many bolded words that serve no meaning, fix it. @Ruuhkis

Comment: There was a hidden message, joking. I'll fix it. :) It was really for lazy people so they don't have to read whole story

Comment: BB aren't approving new accounts [mine's still hanging :(] and you're worried about not getting a playbook!

Comment: I am already registered, but I want to know if the file I submit is right

Comment: I too sent that .bar file. Hoping its the right one...

Comment: Yeah, so stupid that they didn't guide us more :( lets cross our fingers Simon. Also glad to hear I am not the only one here having this problem! :(